# Setting dropdown value not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run this jQuery code to autoselect from a dropdown based on the `data-tipos` attribute. The problem is that it does not run on Safari.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('option[data-id="'+param1+'"]')
        .setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Any help on how to edit the code to run on Safari?

Please find this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6uh57nz3/1/ even if it is not working on this, you have the complete code.

Comment: can you please share the working demo which I can check on safari browser ?

Comment: @Manish yes, please give me a second

Comment: @Manish please find my code here https://jsfiddle.net/6uh57nz3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why, but `setAttribute` is not working in Safari. But, setting the property value of the DOM element works. And this works in all browsers.

```
document.querySelector('option[data-id="' + param1 + '"]')
    .selected = 'selected';
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/duzruz4e/)